# Calculate improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For which p one can calculate this improper integral $\displaystyle \int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{x^p(1-e^{-x})}{1+x^p}dx $?(the "3" is not important!)

I tried $$\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{x^p(1-e^{-x})}{1+x^p}dx=\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{(x^p+1-1)(1-e^{-x})}{1+x^p}dx=\\=\int_{3}^{\infty}(1-e^{-x})dx-\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-x})}{1+x^p}dx=... $$

But I didn't succeed to continue.

Comment: Consider $x^p/(1+x^p)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: At leat for $p>1$, $x^p>1$ in our interval. This makes showing divergence easy. I believe (have not done it) that $p<1$ may be similar.

Comment: As soon as $p>0$ the integrand function converges to $1$ as $x\to +\infty$, leading to a divergent integral.